# View result file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Need a help in jmeter. When we run jmeter from GUI mode, we can see the instant results in UI and that gets auto refreshed in milliseconds or lesser.

But when I run jmeter from command line , in non GUI mode it still creates the result file and I can view it by another jmeter and with the adding an aggregate report listener to it. It opens the results with a pop up alert message but does not refresh it.  For getting the updated results , need to browse and open it again .

So is there any way/plugin to open the file to view with auto refreshed as we can view while running in GUI mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use listeners during test run, even if it is done via another instance of JMeter. Wait for the test to finish and then perform the analysis.

If for some reason looking into interim stats is absolutely required I would recommend running your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper, you'll be able to see some statistics and graphs this way:

[image: Taurus Console]